# Pagination of Wrapper List in VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, pagination

Can someone assist us regarding the error message we get. It seems that obj.hasPrevious doesn't have a value. How can we put a condition here that it will return the hasPrevious method if it has a value.

*This code is for pagination. Rendering of buttons in VF Page*

**System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object 
Class.SearchAdmin2Ctrl.__sfdc_hasPrevious: line 1353, column 1**

CONTROLLER:

```
public Boolean hasPrevious{
    get { return obj.hasPrevious();} set;  
}
```

CUSTOMITERABLE CLASS THAT IMPLEMENTS ITERATOR:

```
// for rendering previous button
global boolean hasPrevious(){         
    system.debug('I am in hasPrevious' + i); 
    if(i <= setPageSize) { 
        return false;              
    } else { 
        return true;             
    }    
}
```

VF PAGE:

```
  <apex:commandButton value="< Previous" action="{!previous}" rendered="   {!hasPrevious}" reRender="btable" />
```

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet obj itself is null that's why accessing obj.hasPrevious() is showing Null pointer exception.

Put a null check before accessing obj.hasPrevious().

Verify the controller code how you are instantiating obj variable.

Comment: Hi @Santanu, the list of wrapper we used in the obj is a collection list. It can be null if the user is not searching for anything. 

Is it possible to put an IF condition inside the get that validates if the variable that is used in the query is not null and then that's the time that it will return the method?

Comment: Sure, you have to do that

Comment: `public Boolean hasPrevious {
        get { if (!String.isEmpty(wrapFilter1.skillName1)) {
              return obj.hasPrevious();} 
               }             
        set;   
    }`

**Non-void method might not return a value or might have statement after a return statement.**

Comment: You have to use return statement

Comment: `public Boolean hasPrevious {
        get { if (!String.isEmpty(wrapFilter1.skillName1)) {
              
              } return obj.hasPrevious();
            }             
        set;   
    } `
\
**System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object 
Class.SearchAdmin2Ctrl.__sfdc_hasPrevious: line 1359, column 1**